# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline does not index periodically

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I am running Jenkins 2.32 with the Multibranch Pipeline plugin. I want the plugin to periodically scan the repository for new branches. I have already tried to use both "Build periodically" with "H/5 * * * *" as well as "Periodically if not otherwise run" set to 5 minutes. Neither worked. Every time I change the configuration, the indexing will run only once!